# Jquery tabs plugin question

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I've created (modified a concept sourced via mr google) a little lightweight tab plugin that works 90% to my satisfaction. However, one very basic key ingredient is missing and it's making me a wee bit sad :).

I can hit the tab and run the client select code (callback function) without issue and have tweaked it to do exactly what I want. However, there is an edge case that is alluding my feeble thought processes. Basically, I'd like to have a tab selected automatically when the page is visited (the last clicked tab index is saved in a cookie), so that the info that the user last looked at is presented to them, rather than the default 1st tab. Now, **I'm well aware that I could use the jquery-ui tab to achieve this aim**, but for a few reasons that I won't bore you with, this isn't an option (***for now!!*** - if what i'm wishing for isn't possible, then I may have to revisit that option).

I've placed the core code on our old chum signor fiddler as it's possibly easier to demonstrate where i've got to, plus will allow you guys to tweak a little easier.

Hope you can help. Here's the link: [Fiddler link to plugin code and simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jimtollan/MUPgz)

all the best...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to accomplish this would be to programmatically trigger a `click` event:

```
$tabs.find("ul li").eq(tabIndex).click();
```

Here's an updated example that automatically selects the third tab:

http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/MUPgz/4/

**Update:**

To encapsulate the call inside the plugin, I've modified it like this:

```
(function($) {
    var activeTab;
    var opts;
    var methods = {
        init: function(options) {
            /* Snip (Previous init code) */
        },
        show: function(index) {
            return this.each(function() {
                $(this).find("ul li").eq(index).trigger("click");
            });
        }
    };

    $.fn.tabify = function(method) {

        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        }
        else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Usage:

```
$tabs.tabify("show", 2);
```

Updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/MUPgz/5/

Comment: +1 andrew - that's pretty good. you'll bag yourself the answer if you can boil that down to $tabs.show(tabIndex) :-) [no pressure then!!]

Comment: @jim: Do you mind if I change it to something like `$tabs.tabify("show", 2)`?

Comment: andrew - nope, that fits better with the namespace, so go for it!! (as an aside, imagine if i said 'yes' :))

Comment: @jim: Haha, not a problem at all.

Comment: andrew - excellent and very quick on the draw. accepted as answer. all the best - wherever you are ;)

Answer (score 0):

any special reason for not use the Official plugin?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: yes, there's a variety of devices that we're targetting that means that we will have to heavily tweak this simple implementation - as i mentioned in my question, too many design details to 'bore' you with, so not an option for now, but watch this space.

Comment: Or the extremely flexible and lightweight jQuery Tools Tabs? http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs/index.html

Comment: i'm going to 'cry' :) - i'm just looking for a punt at getting my implemented *trash* to work as detailed above. but certainly, i'll take a look at that as a 2nd line contingency. thanks for the link!! it certainly looks quite nice, tho a little heavy still. but nice